# Set custom order status for complete PayPal Website Payments Standard payment?

Tags: magento-enterprise, payment, paypal

We are using **Magento EE 1.13.0.2** with the **PayPal Website Payments Standard** payment method. Unfortunately it's not possible to set an order status for paid PayPal orders in the back-end.

We need to set a custom order status when the order has been paid successfully (and not partial). Tutorials to modify the PayPal order status seem to be outdated, wrong or ugly hacks.

From what I gathered:

- the payment updates would be handled by PayPal IPN.
- There is a method `Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn::_registerPaymentCapture()` responsible for "Process completed payment (either full or partial)".
- In `Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn::_registerTransaction()` the request from PayPal is analysed and the payment status is compared to `Mage_Paypal_Model_Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_COMPLETED`.

To be honest I'm not sure what to do with this information. I may rewrite `Mage_Paypal_Model_Ipn::_registerTransaction()` and just add my code:

```
// paid
case Mage_Paypal_Model_Info::PAYMENTSTATUS_COMPLETED:
    $this->_registerPaymentCapture(true);
    // my code here
    break;
```

Of course an event observer (e.g. for one of the order or order state events) would be much nicer but I'm not sure if there is a 100% reliable way to catch that one-time event when the order gets paid completely via PayPal.

Any ideas?

**Update**

We chose to modify our order status flow and don't need to modify the status anymore. I'll leave the question open for some time in case somebody wants to answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem is, there is not even a single event in the whole paypal work flow.

So there are two options:

## Rewrite any of these Paypal models

As you said, just rewrite the model, change the behavior and everything works as expected - hopefully or...

## Hook into `sales_order_save_before`

Then you check for the payment type, which should be `\Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard::$_code` with:

```
protected $_code  = Mage_Paypal_Model_Config::METHOD_WPS;

\Mage_Paypal_Model_Config
-> const METHOD_WPS         = 'paypal_standard';
```

And then, when the status is changed to the one you don't want, change it to the one you want.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, I guess we won't get a better solution in Magento 1.x. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with another solution. After struggling with this issue for a few hours, I realized that in my particular case it didn't matter if only PayPal orders got a particular status (it's for an ERP connection, which searches for orders in a particular status).

PayPal doesn't set the status of the order. It just captures the payment. Magento sets the order's state to *Processing* (see `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment::registerCaptureNotification()`) and sets the status to the default status within that state.

All I had to do was changing the **default status** within the state *Processing* to the status I needed through the admin interface (*System* » *Order Statuses*).

Hope this helps someone!